# Javascript Timers with ASP.NET AJAX pageLoad() function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

```
function pageLoad() {

    clearTimeout("MessagesTimer");
    clearTimeout("NotificationsTimer");

    var MessagesTimer = setTimeout("CheckMessages()", 15000);
    var NotificationsTimer = setTimeout("CheckNotifications()", 15000);
}
```

After spending a couple of hours trying to understand why this isn't working I'm here to ask you guys why these timers won't clear after partial updatepanel postbacks? If there's a full postback the timers would reset but if i got a partial postback the timers will trigger in less than 15000ms depends on how many partial postbacks it could happen that they trigger with 0ms..

How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: I'd like the timers to reset on partial postbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var MessagesTimer;
var NotificationsTimer;

function pageLoad() {
    clearTimeout(MessagesTimer);
    clearTimeout(NotificationsTimer);

    MessagesTimer = setTimeout("CheckMessages()", 15000);
    NotificationsTimer = setTimeout("CheckNotifications()", 15000);
}
```

1. Remove the quotes from the `clearTimeout` lines.
2. Move definition of timers outside `pageLoad` function.